# Is the time complexity of the code snippet O(k*n^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am solving the below LeetCode question:

> Given a digit string, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent.  A mapping of digit to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is given below.

[image: Telephone keypad]

I am trying to understand the complexity of the highly upvoted solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        std::vector< string > vec;
        if(digits.length()==0)
            return vec;

        std::queue< std::string > ans;
        std::string mapping[]={"0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};

        ans.push("");                           
        for(int i=0; i<digits.length(); i++)
        {
            int x = (digits[i]-'0');
            while(ans.front().length()==i)
            {
                std::string t=ans.front();
                ans.pop();                      
                for(int j=0; j<mapping[x].length(); j++)
                {
                    ans.push(t+mapping[x][j]);
                    //cout<<t+mapping[x][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }
        }

        std::string val;
        int size=ans.size();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            val=ans.front();
            ans.pop();
            vec.push_back(val);
        }
        return vec;
    }
};
```

My understanding is as below:

If `n` is the number of digits, then I think the complexity would be `O(k*n^2)`, where `k` is the mapping length (2 -> 'abc', 3 -> 'def' and so on).

The outer-most for loop executes `n` times. During each iteration, we access the front elements in the queue that length equal to `i` (which in worst case would be `n`). This makes it `O(n^2)`. The innermost for loop runs a constant number of times (equal to the mapping length, say `k`). Also, `push()` operation takes constant time. So, the total complexity would be `O(k*n^2)`.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not enough for a comment (yet) - the string `5^n` (`n` instances of `5` in a row, e.g., `5`, `55`, `555`, ...) represents `3^n` strings since each digit can correspond to any of three letters. Indeed, the worst case would be strings of length `n` of `9`s and `7`s, giving `4^n` possibilities. If you return `4^n` strings (the actual strings, not just the number of such strings) I don't think it's realistic to do better than exponential time. If you're returning some sort of compressed representation (like the string of digits itself!), or metadata (number of strings), that's different.

Comment: @Patrick87, could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: O(k^n) is what I come up with.

Comment: @iBug, how so?  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the following notations:

- `n` is the length of the input;
- `k` is the maximum length of a mapping, in your case it is `4` (`"pqrs"` or `"wxyz"`);

...the length of the mapping (the number of elements in `mapping`) is irrelevant to the complexity here.

The complexity of `push` and `pop` on your `std::queue` are `O(1)` (since you are using a `deque`). I will assume that concatenation of strings is `O(1)` (not true in reality).

Trivially, we can see that:

- the inner `for` loop will **always** perform `k` iterations;
- the inner `while` loop will iterate `ans.size()`.

So at each iteration of the outer `for` loop, the body of the inner `for` loop is evaluated `k * ans.size()`  times, and `ans.size()` grows by a factor `k` at each iterations, so you have an exponential behavior:

1. `i = 0`, `ans.size() = 1` -- `k` iterations;
2. `i = 1`, `ans.size() = k` -- `k * k` iterations;
3. `i = 2`, `ans.size() = k * k` -- `k * k * k` iterations;

During the last iteration (`i = n - 1`), the body of the inner `for` loop will be evaluated `k ^ (n - 1)` times, so in total this body will be evaluated:

> k + k^2 + k^3 + ... + k^(n - 1) = (k^n - 1) / (k - 1) - 1

So the inner `for` loop is evaluated `O(k^n)` times, so the complexity of this function is **at least** `O(k^n)` - You need to take into account that concatenating and copying strings are not `O(1)` (in this specific case, you can compute the complexity at each iterations, which is basically `O(i + 1)` at the ith iteration).

This is an exponential complexity, which is much worse than your polynomial `O(k.n^2)` complexity.

Comment: Okay, so I missed an important thing - I assumed the max value of queue `ans` would be `n`, which is not true, since it gets expanded at each iteration.  Could you please elaborate how you concluded its **exponentiation** from "_So at each iteration of the outer for loop, the body of the inner for loop is evaluated k * ans.size() times, and ans.size() grows by a factor k at each iterations_"?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela If you perform `M(i)` operations during iteration `i`, and `M(i + 1) = k * M(i)` (the number of operations per iteration grows with a factor `k`), then you have an exponential behavior (simply from the sum of [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)).

Comment: So in this case, _the number of operations per iteration grows with a factor of `k`_ since we increase the size of the deque in each iteration, correct?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Yes - That's typical in a lot of algorithm, if you have a container `C` and at each iteration you 1) go through the whole container, and 2) multiply the size of the container by something (here `k`), then you have an exponential behavior. On the other hand, if you increase the size of the container by a constant (or a bounded value), you have polynomial behavior.

Comment: Got your point.  In addition to your answer, I liked your above comment (about exponential and polynomial behavior) as well.  I am trying to generalize my understanding of algorithms and so find such application oriented stuff pretty helpful.  Thank you so much.

Comment: BTW, size of the result is `k ** n` so complexity should be at least this number.

Comment: @Jarod42, what do you mean when you say '`result`' and '`k**n`'?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Without going through the algorithm, you now that the final result (the `vector` you are returning) will contain `k ^ n` strings.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela: I use `**` as `^` has different possible meaning (exponential vs xor). Binary operator `**` has no meaning in C++, but some other languages use it for exponential. By "result", I mean size of returned vector.

Comment: *At least O(n)* makes no sense. You should say *at least Θ(n)* or *at least Ω(n)*.